# Best way of modifying and displaying contacts in Android programmatically (Kotlin)?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contacts

I have an app where you get and display contacts from the SIM, and are able to modify specific values for that contact.

Currently I am using ContentResolver to get and modify contacts; unfortunately this means the performance isn't great as each time the contacts are modified they are then all fetched again from the phone which takes some time.

Would it be better to populate a database when the app is first opened and then make any modifications made to both the db and phone?

This way I'm guessing I would only need to load the contacts with ContentResolver on first starting the app, which would save time switching through windows. Or can I persist the contacts object and make changes to both the object and phone? Or is there a better way all together? Just wondering what the best practice would be.

Answer (score 0):

If the user modifies a contact within your app, I assume the app has that contact's contact-id.

If so, you can simply refresh that contact's info, and leave the rest of the info as is.

You should fetch all contacts in your activity's `onResume` callback, so the app will display fresh info whenever it's brought to the foreground.

The fact that you're using a `ContentResolver` does not mean you have to refresh all the contacts to display updated information.